# Is every "prefield" a field?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> **Definition 0.** Call a poset $P$ *well-ranked* iff it is well-founded, and for all $x \in P$, we have that any two maximal subchains in the lowerset generated by $x$ have the same length.
>
> **Definition 1.** For the sake of the question, call a commutative ring $R$ a "prefield" iff for every $R$-module $X$, the finitely-generated submodules of $X$ form a well-ranked poset.

Every field is obviously a prefield. Does the converse hold?

Comment: *Remark.* I can't quite tell whether or not being a prefield implies being Artinian.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your definitions correctly, any finite product of fields, including the zero ring, has this property.